# CodeIgniter 3.1.0 form validation issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

CodeIgniter 3.1.0 form validation issue.

I have an CodeIgniter application which use 2 databases:

1. Master database: "main_db".
2. Slave database: "client1", "client2"....

When user visit my website, I track the user url and get the client information. Then I connect to master `database(main_db)` and get the slave database information. After getting the correct slave database information, then I connect to slave database and the entire application use the slave database.

I have a table named "product_category". with a column name "category_name".

When I am trying to validate the form like

```
is_unique[product_category.category_name]
```

When I run the script, the codeigniter use the master database whereas the using slave database is expected.

```
Table 'main_db.product_category' doesn't exist
```

Comment: how do you build up the connection to the database ?
you should show us some Model Code or Config Definitions

Comment: $db_client=$this->session->userdata('db_info');
$this->db2 = $this->load->database($db_client['client'], TRUE);
$this->db=$this->db2->initialize() ;